# Create matrix of repeated columns based on min and max of a vector

Tags: matlab, matrix

lets say my inputs are v = [1, 3] and i = 4;
I need to construct this

```
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3
```

Any help please how could I do that ?
All I know to do is this =>

```
V = (min(v):1:max(v));
V = V(:);
```

this way I get the

```
1
2
3
```

Now what do I do from here ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: take a look at [`repmat`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html)

Comment: TY!
repmat(V, 1, i) 
Worked! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [**`ndgrid`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html):

```
v = [1, 3]
ii = 4

out = ndgrid(v(1):v(end),1:ii)
```

---

```
out =

     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3
```